# How to colour nth <td> element of a HTML table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I tried using:

```
td:nth-of-type(5).style.backgroundColor("blue");
```

to colour 5th `<td>` element using JavaScript but I received:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: nth is not defined
>       at :1:4

What is the correct code to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use css like that in javascript. You'll need to use selector and assign the value like:

```
document.querySelector('td:nth-of-type(5)').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Look at the documentation for [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS variable and change it's value in JS like so (please look at [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Browser_compatibility) for CSS variables):

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-color', "blue");
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: initial; 
}

td:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>a.1</td>
    <td>a.2</td>
    <td>a.3</td>
    <td>a.4</td>
    <td>a.5</td>
    <td>a.6</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>b.1</td>
    <td>b.2</td>
    <td>b.3</td>
    <td>b.4</td>
    <td>b.5</td>
    <td>b.6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, for something a little more browser compatible, you could use `querySelectorAll()` with `.forEach()` to loop through all selected elements using your selector:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-of-type(5)").forEach(td => {
  td.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>a.1</td>
    <td>a.2</td>
    <td>a.3</td>
    <td>a.4</td>
    <td>a.5</td>
    <td>a.6</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>b.1</td>
    <td>b.2</td>
    <td>b.3</td>
    <td>b.4</td>
    <td>b.5</td>
    <td>b.6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```